# How to save and load an array of complex numbers using numpy.savetxt?

Tags: python, numpy, complex-numbers

I want to use [`numpy.savetxt()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) to save an array of complex numbers to a text file. Problems:

- If you save the complex array with the default format string, the imaginary part is discarded.
- If you use `fmt='%s'`, then `numpy.loadtxt()` can't load it unless you specify `dtype=complex, converters={0: lambda s: complex(s)}`. Even then, if there are NaN's in the array, loading still fails.

It looks like someone has inquired about this [multiple](http://www.mail-archive.com/numpy-discussion@scipy.org/msg16519.html) [times](http://www.mail-archive.com/numpy-discussion@scipy.org/msg22941.html) on the Numpy mailing list and even filed a [bug](http://projects.scipy.org/numpy/ticket/1573), but has not gotten a response. Before I put something together myself, is there a canonical way to do this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's easier and saves a few temporary arrays to just reinterpret the array as a real array.

Saving:

```
numpy.savetxt('outfile.txt', array.view(float))
```

Loading:

```
array = numpy.loadtxt('outfile.txt').view(complex)
```

If you prefer to have real and imaginary part on the same line in the file, you can use

```
numpy.savetxt('outfile.txt', array.view(float).reshape(-1, 2))
```

or

```
array = numpy.loadtxt('outfile.txt').view(complex).reshape(-1)
```

respectively.

(Note that neither `view()` nor `reshape()` copies the array -- it will just reinterpret the same data in a different way.)

**Addendum from the question asker:**

If you want to save more than one complex array in the same file, you can do it like so:

```
numpy.savetxt('outfile.txt', numpy.column_stack([
    array1.view(float).reshape(-1, 2),
    array2.view(float).reshape(-1, 2),
]))

array1, array2 = numpy.loadtxt('outfile.txt', unpack=True).view(complex)
```

The reshaping is necessary because `numpy.view()` doesn't operate on strided arrays.

Comment: Excellent! Short and elegant.

Answer (score 6):

Here's my solution, in case anybody hits this question from Google.

Saving:

```
numpy.savetxt('outfile.txt', numpy.column_stack([array.real, array.imag]))
```

Loading:

```
array_real, array_imag = numpy.loadtxt('outfile.txt', unpack=True)
array = array_real + 1j * array_imag
```

I will still award the checkmark to a better solution!