# loading complex numbers with numpy.loadtxt

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, complex-numbers

I know that if I want to save and load arrays of complex numbers with numpy, I can use the method described here: [How to save and load an array of complex numbers using numpy.savetxt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6494102/how-to-save-and-load-an-array-of-complex-numbers-using-numpy-savetxt/) .

Assume however, that someone did not know about this and saved their array `numbers` with `numpy.savetxt("numbers.txt",numbers`), producing a file with entries of the form

```
(0.000000000000000000e+00+-2.691033635430225765e-02j)  .
```

In this case

```
numbers_load = numpy.loadtxt("numbers.txt").view(complex)
```

will, predictably, fail in the sense of

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: (0.000000000000000000e+00+-2.691033635430225765e-02j)  .
```

What would be an easy way of extracting the complex numbers from this file (without generating a different version of it)?

Answer (score 8):

Specifying the data type like:

```
np.loadtxt("numbers.txt", dtype=np.complex_)
```

works for me.

Comment: This is brilliant! Much easier than all the other answers here

Answer (score 3):

Before saving the array, you should use `.view(float)` to convert it to an array of `float`s, and then `.view(complex)` to convert the `float`s back to `complex` numbers on loading.

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: A = np.array([1+2j, 2+5j, 3-4j, -3+1j])

In [3]: A.view(float)
Out[3]: array([ 1.,  2.,  2.,  5.,  3., -4., -3.,  1.])

In [4]: np.savetxt("numbers.txt", A.view(float))

In [5]: np.loadtxt("numbers.txt")
Out[5]: array([ 1.,  2.,  2.,  5.,  3., -4., -3.,  1.])

In [6]: np.loadtxt("numbers.txt").view(complex)
Out[6]: array([ 1.+2.j,  2.+5.j,  3.-4.j, -3.+1.j])
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use [**converters**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) to handle the custom format. The only problem that prevents reading the complex value properly is the `+-` in `1+-2j`, replacing them to `1-2j` would work.

```
>>> numpy.savetxt('1.txt', numpy.array([2.3+4.5j, 6.7-0.89j]))

>>> numpy.loadtxt('1.txt', dtype=complex)  # <- doesn't work directly
ValueError: complex() arg is a malformed string

>>> numpy.loadtxt('1.txt', dtype=complex, converters={0: lambda s: complex(s.decode().replace('+-', '-'))})
array([ 2.3+4.5j ,  6.7-0.89j])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can't modify the file, you can transform the strings as you read them in line by line.

```
import numpy as np
import re

# a regular expression that picks out the two components of the complex number
reg = re.compile('(-?\d.\d*e[+-]\d\d)\+(-?\d.\d*e[+-]\d\d)')
# a function that returns a properly formatted string
edit = lambda s: reg.search(s).expand(r'\1 \2')

with open("numbers.txt", 'r') as fobj:
    # calling map applies the edit function to each line of numbers.txt in turn
    numbers_load = np.loadtxt(map(edit, fobj))
print(numbers_load) # [ 0.         -0.02691034]
print(numbers_load.view('complex')) # [ 0.-0.02691034j]
```

Answer (score 0):

The docs for `savetxt` talk about `fmt` options for a complex array.

Starting with a 1d array:

```
In [17]: np.arange(5)+np.arange(5,0,-1)*1j
Out[17]: array([ 0.+5.j,  1.+4.j,  2.+3.j,  3.+2.j,  4.+1.j])
In [18]: arr = np.arange(5)+np.arange(5,0,-1)*1j
```

The default is to write the numbers, one `()` string per line.  Reading that with `loadtxt` (or `genfromtxt`) is going to be a problem.  It will have to be loaded as a string, and then converted line by line.

```
In [19]: np.savetxt('test.txt',arr)
In [20]: cat test.txt
 (0.000000000000000000e+00+5.000000000000000000e+00j)
 (1.000000000000000000e+00+4.000000000000000000e+00j)
 (2.000000000000000000e+00+3.000000000000000000e+00j)
 (3.000000000000000000e+00+2.000000000000000000e+00j)
 (4.000000000000000000e+00+1.000000000000000000e+00j)
```

It says I can specify a format for the real and imaginary parts, in which case it saves it as 2 columns.  That's easy to read with `loadtxt`.

```
In [21]: np.savetxt('test.txt',arr, fmt='%f %f')
In [22]: cat test.txt
0.000000 5.000000
1.000000 4.000000
2.000000 3.000000
3.000000 2.000000
4.000000 1.000000

In [23]: np.loadtxt('test.txt')
Out[23]: 
array([[ 0.,  5.],
       [ 1.,  4.],
       [ 2.,  3.],
       [ 3.,  2.],
       [ 4.,  1.]])

In [25]: np.loadtxt('test.txt').view(complex)
Out[25]: 
array([[ 0.+5.j],
       [ 1.+4.j],
       [ 2.+3.j],
       [ 3.+2.j],
       [ 4.+1.j]])
```

With a 2d complex array I need to specify fmt for all columns

```
In [28]: arr1=np.array((arr, arr*.1, arr+1))
In [29]: arr1
Out[29]: 
array([[ 0.0+5.j ,  1.0+4.j ,  2.0+3.j ,  3.0+2.j ,  4.0+1.j ],
       [ 0.0+0.5j,  0.1+0.4j,  0.2+0.3j,  0.3+0.2j,  0.4+0.1j],
       [ 1.0+5.j ,  2.0+4.j ,  3.0+3.j ,  4.0+2.j ,  5.0+1.j ]])

In [33]: np.savetxt('test.txt',arr1, fmt=['%f %f']*5)
In [34]: cat test.txt
0.000000 5.000000 1.000000 4.000000 2.000000 3.000000 3.000000 2.000000 4.000000 1.000000
0.000000 0.500000 0.100000 0.400000 0.200000 0.300000 0.300000 0.200000 0.400000 0.100000
1.000000 5.000000 2.000000 4.000000 3.000000 3.000000 4.000000 2.000000 5.000000 1.000000
In [35]: np.loadtxt('test.txt').view(complex)
Out[35]: 
array([[ 0.0+5.j ,  1.0+4.j ,  2.0+3.j ,  3.0+2.j ,  4.0+1.j ],
       [ 0.0+0.5j,  0.1+0.4j,  0.2+0.3j,  0.3+0.2j,  0.4+0.1j],
       [ 1.0+5.j ,  2.0+4.j ,  3.0+3.j ,  4.0+2.j ,  5.0+1.j ]])
```

The docs show a long format string with all columns, but evidently a list of strings works

```
In [36]: ['%f %f']*5
Out[36]: ['%f %f', '%f %f', '%f %f', '%f %f', '%f %f']
```

`savetxt` joins that list with the delimiter to make one long format string.

```
In [37]: np.savetxt('test.txt',arr1, fmt=['%f %f']*5, delimiter=',')
In [38]: cat test.txt
0.000000 5.000000,1.000000 4.000000,2.000000 3.000000,3.000000 2.000000,4.000000 1.000000
...
```

For `loadtxt` the delimiter between complex parts and columns has to be compatible:

```
In [39]: np.savetxt('test.txt',arr1, fmt=['%f %f']*5, delimiter='  ')
In [40]: cat test.txt
0.000000 5.000000  1.000000 4.000000  2.000000 3.000000  3.000000 2.000000  4.000000 1.000000
...
```

In sum, the save/load round trip will be easiest if the `save` is done with load compatible formats.